# Why Array.from(new Set) would not work in React jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to generate a dropdown options from GraphQL query result which is an object that contains a an array. Since TypeScript doesn't support iteration on objects, I was trying to use pure JavaScript to iterate through data. When I simply write it following way it works:

```
const unique = Array.from(
 new Set(data.PlayerDetails.map((item: any) => item.country))
);
console.log(unique);
```

But when I put that within JSX it doesn't work. What could be the reason?

```
...
return (
<p>
  <Bold>Players: </Bold>
  <select className="form-control">
    {Array.from(
      new Set(
        data.PlayerDetails.map((player: any) => {
          return (
            <option key={player.id} value={player.country}>
              {player.country}
            </option>
          );
        })
      )
    )}
  </select>
</p>
);
```

**Expecting:** duplicates removed in the `<option>...</option>`.

**Actual Result:** `<option>...</option>` still shows all data with duplicates but the former code "unique" shows data without duplicates.

Comment: You're using 2 different properties to create the set from. One is `initialUnits`, the other is `playerDetails`. Maybe `PlayerDetails` is just an empty array?

Comment: *"Since TypeScript doesn't support iteration on objects..."* Neither does JavaScript. Plain objects are not iterable. But `Object.keys`, `Object.values`, and `Object.entries` provide iterable information about an object's contents.

Comment: @Baruch that was just a typo.

Comment: There's no point to `Array.from(new Set(/*...code creating an array of elements guaranteed to be unique*/))`. Just use the *code creating an array of elements guaranteed to be unique* directly. Every `<option>...</option>` will be a unique object.

Comment: "Doesn't work" how?

Comment: I had duplicates which I was trying to remove. So "unique" shows data without duplicates but `<option>...</option>` doesn't

Comment: @shaz - That code won't remove duplicate players. Again, each `<option>...</option>` will be a new, unique object.

Comment: But `Array.from(
    new Set(data.initialUnits.map((item: any) => item.country))
  );` this does show data without any duplicates.

Comment: @shaz - Yes, *that* would, because...ah, I get the nature of your question now.

Comment: @shaz JSX elements are POJOs (Plain 'ol JavaScript Objects) - When you return a new POJO for every element, each element is guaranteed to be unique, because `{} !== {}` (objects look the same, but have different identities).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with JSX, you're doing two very different things in those code snippets.

In your first, you're eliminating duplicates by mapping your player entries to just their country value and passing that through a `Set` to get only unique country values.

In your code creating `<option>` elements, you're *creating objects*. Those are going to be unique, because every object is unique, even if it has the same contents.

My first thought was to pre-filter the array of player data to remove duplicates, then map the result to `<option>` elements. For example:

```
const countries = new Set();
const uniquePlayers = data.PlayerDetails.filter(({country}) => {
    if (countries.has(country)) {
        return false;
    }
    countries.add(country);
    return true;
});
return (
    <select className="form-control">
    {uniquePlayers.map((player/*: any*/) => {
        return (
            <option key={player.id} value={player.country}>
              {player.country}
            </option>
        );
    })}
    </select>
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const data = {
    PlayerDetails: [
        {
            id: 1,
            country: "China"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            country: "USA"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            country: "Finland"
        },
        {
            id: 1, // Duplicate
            country: "China"
        }
    ]
};

const Example = () => {
    const countries = new Set();
    const uniquePlayers = data.PlayerDetails.filter(({country}) => {
        if (countries.has(country)) {
            return false;
        }
        countries.add(country);
        return true;
    });
    return (
        <select className="form-control">
        {uniquePlayers.map((player/*: any*/) => {
            return (
                <option key={player.id} value={player.country}>
                  {player.country}
                </option>
            );
        })}
        </select>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

...but actually, you can do the unique check and create the `<option>` elements in a single pass. You probably don't have so many `<option>` elements that it's important from a performance perspective, but it makes the code simpler:

```
const options = new Map();
for (const player of data.PlayerDetails) {
    const {country} = player;
    if (!options.has(country)) {
        options.set(
            country,
            <option key={player.id} value={player.country}>
              {player.country}
            </option>
        );
    }
}
return (
    <select className="form-control">
    {options.values()}
    </select>
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const data = {
    PlayerDetails: [
        {
            id: 1,
            country: "China"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            country: "USA"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            country: "Finland"
        },
        {
            id: 1, // Duplicate
            country: "China"
        }
    ]
};

const Example = () => {
    const options = new Map();
    for (const player of data.PlayerDetails) {
        const {country} = player;
        if (!options.has(country)) {
            options.set(
                country,
                <option key={player.id} value={player.country}>
                  {player.country}
                </option>
            );
        }
    }
    return (
        <select className="form-control">
        {options.values()}
        </select>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you have omitted all the types. But I need to use them since I am using `TypeScript` like, `player: any`

Comment: @shaz - TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, you never *have* to have types. If you want to, I figured you'd be able to figure out what you need to add. For most of the above, I'm sure TypeScript can infer the types. You may have to specify types for the `Map` (probably `new Map<String, object>()`), but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.from` second argument, that is a **map function**.

The `Array.from` signature is the following, see [Array.from docs on MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```
Array.from(arrayLike, mapFn, thisArg)
```

Try something like this

```js
return (
  <p>
    <Bold>Players: </Bold>
    <select className="form-control">
      {Array.from(
        // First argument, arrayLike: using Set to deduplicate.
        new Set(data.PlayerDetails),

        // Second argument, map function.
        (player) => (
          <option key={player.id} value={player.country}>
            {player.country}
          </option>
        )
      )}
    </select>
  </p>
);
```